# Is there a better way to structure these database tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I'm struggling with the best way to design/query my db on a new Rails app. This is what I have in place right now:

```
documents:
  title
  has_many :document_sections

document_sections:
  belongs_to :document
  habtm :resources

resources_document_sections:
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :document_section

resources:
  text
```

So it's easy to say `document_section.resources`. But `document.resources` is giving me trouble

The only way I've found to do it so far is to collect the document section ids, and then run a second query:

```rb
d = Document.last
s_ids = d.document_section_ids

Resource.joins(:document_sections)
        .where(document_sections: { id: s_ids })
        .uniq
```

So this starts bad, and gets worse as the queries get more complicated. It's becoming quite a headache every time I have to touch this relationship.

I'm wondering if there is a different pattern that I could follow in laying out these tables, such that querying against them is not such a headache? Or is there a better querying strategy that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document has no relationships. You need to add  something to *both* models in a relationship, you can't just add it to `document_sections` and expect `documents` to have any kind of relationship to anything.

You need to add a `has_many ... through:` to your Document:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :document_sections
  has_many :relationships, through: :document_sections
end
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to add in the `has_many` on the document. The `has_many :through` does exactly what I want, though... I'm surprised! For some reason I thought it wouldn't track across the many-to-many relationship. Thanks!